# Objective C How to merge multiple NSMutableArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, for-loop, nsmutablearray

I have few `NSMutableArrays` such as arr1,arr2,arr3,arr4. How can I merge all the `NSMutableArrays` together? Or is there any way to append in one array multiple times?

**Example:**

```
arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
//first loop
for(condition){
    [arr addObject:firstLoopValue];
}
//second loop
for(condition){
    [arr addObject:secondLoopValue];
}
//third loop
for(condition){
    [arr addObject:thirdLoopValue];
}
```

And at the end final result `{firstLoopValue...secondLoopValue...thirdLoopValue}`

I am new to iOS that's why not sure if it's possible. Thanks in advance

**EDIT**
I have tried in both ways like below:

```
rCodeArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
rDateArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
rAmountArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

jCodeArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
jDateArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
jAmountArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
jBalanceArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSArray *component = [journal getComponents:custCode];
for(int i = 0; i < [component count]; i++){

    list = [component objectAtIndex:i];

    NSArray *timestamp = [list.jDate componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    NSString *splitdate = timestamp[0];

    [jCodeArr addObject:list.jCode];
    [jDateArr addObject:splitdate];
    [jAmountArr addObject:list.jAmount];
    [jBalanceArr addObject:list.jOutstanding];
}
NSArray *rcom = [receipt getComponents:custCode];
for(int j = 0; j < [rcom count]; j++){

    rList = [rcom objectAtIndex:j];

    NSArray *rtime = [rList.rDate componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    NSString *rsplit = rtime[0];

    [rCodeArr addObject:rList.rCode];
    [rDateArr addObject:rsplit];
    [rAmountArr addObject:rList.rAmount];
    [rBalanceArr addObject:@"N/A"];
}

lblOneArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:rCodeArr];

    [lblOneArray addObjectsFromArray:jCodeArr];
    lblTwoArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:rDateArr];

    [lblTwoArray addObjectsFromArray:jDateArr];
    lblThreeArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:rAmountArr];

    [lblThreeArray addObjectsFromArray:jAmountArr];
    lblFourArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:jBalanceArr];
    [lblFourArray addObjectsFromArray:rBalanceArr];
```

**AND**

```
lblOneArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
lblTwoArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
lblThreeArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
lblFourArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[lblOneArray addObjectsFromArray:rCodeArr];
[lblOneArray addObjectsFromArray:jCodeArr];

[lblTwoArray addObjectsFromArray:rDateArr];
[lblTwoArray addObjectsFromArray:jDateArr];

[lblThreeArray addObjectsFromArray:jAmountArr];
[lblThreeArray addObjectsFromArray:jAmountArr];

[lblFourArray addObjectsFromArray:rBalanceArr];
[lblFourArray addObjectsFromArray:jBalanceArr];
```

But it's still crashing with the message ***** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 5 beyond bounds [0 .. 4]'**

**NOTE** All these are NSMutableArray

Comment: put breakpoint and see on which line it is crashing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do

```
arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[arr addObjectsFromArray:anArray1];
[arr addObjectsFromArray:anArray2];
[arr addObjectsFromArray:anArray3];
```

Comment: let me try this

Comment: my app is crashing

Comment: @MohammadJulfikar What does the crash say?

Comment: Have you created your lblOneArray, lblTwoArray as mutable arrays?

Comment: yes I created them as mutable array. the crash says index out of range

Comment: Then you might not have created a mutable array or it goes out of bounds somewhere else. Can you add your code here

Comment: Can you paste the full error stacktrace. possibly which line does it crash. its some other issue

Comment: it's throwing exception in main.m UIApplicationMain and the error message is in the question

Comment: your ans is also correct but another guy answered same thing earlier than you thats why had to accept that. upvoted you already

Comment: Ha ha no issues. But if you see the timestamp mine was earlier. But yeah, it doesn't matter as long as your query is answered. Thanks for the upvote though :)

Answer (score 4):

You can create a final array by adding all array like below

```
NSMutableArray *newArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[newArray addObjectsFromArray:firstArray];

[newArray addObjectsFromArray:secondArray];
```

It is not crashing as I have checked with below code

```
NSMutableArray *arr1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1", @"2", nil];
NSMutableArray *arr2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"3", @"4", nil];

NSMutableArray *finalArray  = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[finalArray addObjectsFromArray:arr1];
[finalArray addObjectsFromArray:arr2];
```

Comment: I used like this  `[lblOneArray addObjectsFromArray:rCodeArr];
    [lblOneArray addObjectsFromArray:jCodeArr];
    [lblTwoArray addObjectsFromArray:rDateArr];
    [lblTwoArray addObjectsFromArray:jDateArr];
    [lblThreeArray addObjectsFromArray:jAmountArr];
    [lblThreeArray addObjectsFromArray:rAmountArr];
    [lblFourArray addObjectsFromArray:jBalanceArr];` and it's crashin

Comment: If it is crashing then may be u r doing something wrong. Make sure you are using mutable array

Comment: I have edited the question with code. can you check now?

Comment: As you mention in code that it is crashing with [__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 5 beyond bounds [0 .. 4] then issue with in list = [component objectAtIndex:i]; or rList = [rcom objectAtIndex:j];

Comment: `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *jCode,*jDate,*jAmount,*jOutstanding,*jId,*jCust_code,*jPos,*jCancelled;`

`@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *rCode,*rDate,*rAmount,*rId,*rCust_code,*rCancelled;`

these are the objects I have.. why should it cause the error?

Comment: your answer is correct. i forgot to alloc my fourth array..silly mistake

Answer (score 3):

To combine multiple arrays you can initialize array with elements of the 1st array and then add elements from it:

```
NSMutableArray* arr1 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: firstLoopValue];
[arr1 addObjectsFromArray: secondLoopValue];
[arr1 addObjectsFromArray: thirdLoopValue];
[arr1 addObjectsFromArray: forthLoopValue];
```

Comment: App crashing with message **[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 5 beyond bounds [0 .. 4]**

Answer (score 0):

1) By object

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"xyz" ,nil];

array = [array arrayByAddingObject:@"abc"];

array = [array arrayByAddingObject:@"kart"];
```

2) By Array

```
NSMutableArray* main = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: temp];

[main addObjectsFromArray: temp2];

[main addObjectsFromArray: temp3];

[main addObjectsFromArray: temp4];
```